# How to take input type Date in HTML and use in angular7 component.ts file?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to add date/calendar in my angular7 form but I do not know how. Please help. I'm new and trying to learn by creating a simple angular7 form with .net web api and microsoft sql server.

1. User.component.html file

```
<html>
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> USERNAME</label>
        <input name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.UserName" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> FULLNAME</label>
        <input name="FullName" #FullName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.FullName" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> MULTIPLE ROLES</label>
        <input name="MultipleRoles" #MultipleRoles="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.MultiplesRoles" class="form- 
        control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> STATUS</label>
        <input name="Status" #Status="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.Status" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Create Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Create By </label>
        <input name="CreateBy" #CreateBy="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.CreateBy" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

2. User.cs

   namespace UserManagement3.Models
       {
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

   ```
   public partial class User
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public string FullName { get; set; }
       public string MultipleRoles { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
       public string CreateBy { get; set; }}}
   ```
3. User.model.ts

   ```
   export class User {

   Id: number;
    UserName: string;
   FullName: string;
   MultipleRoles: string;
   Status: string;
   CreateDate: string;
   CreateBy: string;}
   ```
4. user.component.ts

```
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
 if (form != null) {
 form.resetForm();
 this.UserService.formData = {
   Id : null,
   UserName: '',
   FullName: '',
   MultipleRoles: '',
   Status: '',
   CreateDate: '',
   CreateBy: '',
   };
  }
}
```

I want to add datepicker/calendar in the CreateDate form. and pass the form in db in mssm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to make use of any external libraries or dependencies, you can simply add another `<input>` element, and set the `type` attribute as `date`. This will allow the user to input the values in date format, or use the built in date picker interface, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

```
<input type="date">
```

Since you are using template driven forms (two-way data binding), feel free to make the following changes to your code.

On your component.html, add this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Create Date</label>
  <input name="Status" #Status="ngModel" type="date" [(ngModel)]="UserService.formData.CreateDate" class="form-control">
</div>
```

You should be able to get the date value (in `string` format) on your component.ts.

However, do take note of [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility). Safari and IE do not support this attribute value.

Alternatively, you can make use of the [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview), or [ngBootstrap Datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples). These are very popular datepicker libraries which are widely used by developers working on Angular.

Comment: thank you sir. I didn't know in ts file it is taken as string eventhough in mssm is date type and in html is date type.

Comment: You're welcome! But as I mentioned on my answer, you have to be aware that this `input type="date"` won't work in Safari!